# Set color through color code in c#

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am trying to add color in c# code, with the following color code for example.

> ListTreeView.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

This is working..but I want to add this color as color code so I am add as

> System.Windows.Media

Could someone give me an example with

> System.Drawing

So what I can do the following:

> ListTreeView.Background = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFE7EFF2");

This gives me error ; Any Ideas?

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Is that code right? As @ho1 states `ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E7EFF2")` will work for an RGB hex value - but you have an 8 digit string. Do you have the alpha value in there too?

Comment: This is fully WPF, but still it is not working.

see the whole code..

                            tlvi.Background = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFE7EFF2");

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to get the colour with alpha included from a hex string in this way.

I think your answer depends on where you're getting the colour and alpha values from.

The RGB colour alone can be parsed from an HTML hex string:

```
Color colour = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E7EFF2");
```

If you have a separate alpha value you can then apply this ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hstcth9.aspx)):

```
Color colour = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E7EFF2");
Color transparent = Color.FromArgb(128, colour);
```

Alternatively you may need to parse the string and split it out to convert the hex pairs into integer values.

PS excuse English spelling, but colour should definitely have a 'u' in it :)

Comment: so is armor/armour, defense/defence, grey/gray etc. the point gets across tho. but i wonder, since wpf has its own "fromArgb"function but it somehow doesnt use the correct alpha setting? why

Comment: @ThrowingDwarf .Net's `Color` components aren't very good. There are lots of basic functions missing and bugs like `GetBrightness()` returning the luminosity/lightness (0 is black, 1 is white) rather than brightness (0 still black, but 1 is the colour at full intensity) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732836

Comment: yes but for example if i get the hex generated from the color selector (#FFFBB510) its goldish yellow (rgb 251,181,16) full alpha. color converters like hexcolortool.com doesn't even accept is as a valid color. and NEITHER does wpf accept this hex, well as far as ive experienced. i ended up using "newBtn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,251,181,16));"

Comment: if only they would add the ability to use a CSS stylesheet smh

Answer (score 7):

`ListTreeView` isn't a standard `Control` provided by the framework, so you'll have to consult their documentation. In general, though, you can use **[`System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx)** or **[`System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833.aspx)**. Here's how you'd do it with a TreeView:

```
TreeView t = ...
t.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(0xff00ff00); // Fully opaque, 100% green.
// or:
t.BackgroundColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("green");
```

Comment: I don't think there's a `FromArgb` overload that takes a hex string is there?

Comment: Er, sorry, that's supposed to be just a hex integer. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml`.

Comment: This isn't the right way to do it if you want (A)RGB values, which is apparently what he's after. `FromHtml` will throw an exception if you use anything but an HTML color.

Comment: @John: Sorry, don't know what you're talking about. `Color c = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFE7EFF2")` works fine and if I then do `button1.BackColor = c;` it'll make the button some blueish colour. Are you saying that it's the wrong colour?

Comment: @ho1: When I use "#FFE7EFF2" with ColorTranslator, it's exactly the same color as "#00E7EFF2" (which should be invisible since the alpha channel is zero, right?).

Comment: @John: Don't know, I don't know much about graphics and colours, just confused by your comment about an exception.

Comment: see things is that I am trying to add background color into the ListTreeView 
so 

ListTreeView.Background =System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00E7EFF2");

it will give error so what i can do..

Comment: @Jitendra: First thing you need to do is to actually post what the error is. Since `ListTreeView` isn't a standard control (as far as I know) I can't try to replicate the error since I don't know what code you're using, the error message might be enough for someone to know what the problem is but it would also be useful if you could say where you got the `ListTreeView` from? Is it a control you've bought or something you've made yourself or from some article on codeproject etc?

Comment: ya this is my own control so I had made this control and I am using 
this control...
for eg..
I had made a class for ListTreeView and i am use this control every 
where..
so tell me what to do...

Comment: ColorTranslator.FromHtml() works with both a 6 char hex value and an 8 char hex value.  This should have been selected as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Color.FromArgb method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh.aspx).

Btw, shouldn't it be [Treeview.BackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.backcolor.aspx) instead?

Grz, Kris.